# VSCode Windows can't find typescript module

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VSCode Windows can not find typescript module unless adding ext to the file.

But the same project in WSL:ubuntu works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript you have to reference to the compiled .js file. In your case it would look like this: `export * from './types.js'`. This is, because the browser actually only uses the compiled .js files.

Answer (score 0):

Vscode require using the file extension. so just add `.ts` and it will work in both.